# monodevelop bug on creating new solution

Tags: mono

Just installed mono-complete and monodevelop on my raspberry pi 4. When I run monodevelop, I see the IDE/GUI, but when I try to create a new solution (.NET/Console Project), when I click "Next" nothing appears (I would expect to see the entry form for providing a project name and a directory location). If I click "Next" again, I get an error message "Illegal Solution Name." Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: read everything on the screen ... use a valid solution name

Comment: There is nowhere to type in a solution name.

Comment: sounds like a bug ... maybe the entry field is somehow hidden ... try pressing the TAB key to see if the cursor jumps someplace invisible ... if it does, then press some keys, like abc123